# Использование селектора :not

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Привет. У меня есть блок .blogp_text. В нем есть картинка. Как сделать padding для всего внутри этого блока кроме картинок, используя селектор not? Пробую так, но не выходит:

```
.blogp_text:not(img) {padding: 0 20px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.blogp_text > :not(img) {padding: 0 20px;}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хватила пробела между классом и :not

Answer (score 1):

```
.blogp_text *:not(img){padding: 0 20px;}
```